# PySpark, Spark SQL: Pivot last 3 distinct rows by user to 3 columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using PySpark and Spark SQL, I have a table like this:

```
id | Client_Num | Value  |    Date 
 1 |     14     |   A    | 1483695557 
 2 |     14     |   B    | 1486395557 
 3 |     14     |   C    | 1488814757 
 4 |     14     |   A    | 1491489557 
 5 |     14     |   D    | 1478446757 
 6 |     19     |   X    | 1483695557 
 7 |     19     |   Y    | 1486395557 
 8 |     19     |   Z    | 1478446757 
 9 |     19     |   W    | 1491489557 
 10|     21     |   R    | 1468446757
```

I want to pivot last 3 values to columns by user.
the result is supposed to be something like this:

```
id | Client_Num | Value_1  | Value_2 | Value_3
 1 |     14     |    A     |    B    |   C
 2 |     19     |    X     |    Y    |   W
 3 |     21     |    R     |         |
```

Sorry for the description of the problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine window functions and `pivot`. Required imports:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, desc, first, lit, row_number
```

Data:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, 14, "A", 1483695557 ), (2, 14, "B", 1486395557 ),
    (3, 14, "C", 1488814757 ), (4, 14, "A", 1491489557 ),
    (5, 14, "D", 1478446757 ), (6, 19, "X", 1483695557 ),
    (7, 19, "Y", 1486395557 ), (8, 19, "Z", 1478446757 ),
    (9, 19, "W", 1491489557 ), (10, 21, "R", 1468446757 ),
]).toDF(["id", "client_num", "value", "date"])
```

Window definition (Spark 2.1+ syntax):

```
w = Window.partitionBy("client_num").orderBy(desc("date"))
```

First let's filter out the three latest records:

```
latest = df.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w)).where(col("rn") <= 3)
```

add a prefix and `pivot`:

```
(latest
    .withColumn("rn", concat(lit("value_"), col("rn")))
    .groupBy("client_num")
    .pivot("rn", ["value_{}".format(i) for i in [1, 2, 3]])
    .agg(first("value")))
```

with the result as shown below:

```
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
|client_num|value_1|value_2|value_3|
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
|        19|      W|      Y|      X|
|        14|      A|      C|      B|
|        21|      R|   null|   null|
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

You can adjust the ordering by modifying `orderBy` clause of the window.

If you want unique values you can aggregate data before adding `row_number`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max

latest = (df
    .groupBy("client_num", "value").agg(max("date").alias("date"))
    .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w)).where(col("rn") <= 3))
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I still get duplicated values in some rows. each value must be unique.